# I can't program the condition for the value to be deleted in the BD column if this value is >=1 and <= 15

Tags: if-statement

I tried in several ways to develop the condition to delete values equal to and greater than 1 and equal to and less than 15 in the "BD" column of my excel spreadsheet but this programming is not accepted. I believe it is a problem fo wrong syntax.

```
Dim W As Worksheet
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim Ultima_Linha As Long
    
    Set W = Sheets("CONOB")
    Ultima_Linha = W.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Call transformadataemdia
    
    With W
    For linha = Ultima_Linha To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(linha, "j") = "4" Then
    .Rows(linha).Delete
    End If
    
    If Cells(linha, "BD").Value(<=1 and >= 15) Then
    .Rows(linha).Delete
    End If
    Next linha
    
    End With
```

I expected to delete rows in column "BD"  with values equal to and greater than 1 and equal to and less than 15 in the "BD" column of my excel spreadsheet but this programming is not accepted. I believe it is a problem

Comment: I would expect something like `If Cells(linha, "BD" ).Value >= 1 and Cells(linha, "BD" ).Value <=15 Then ... `

Comment: It would help if you show any error message, and add tags probably for 'excel' and 'vba'